# How to end a script when is function is done?

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I have a Blogger Blog, and I want to setup a link that auto open when someone visit me. I found some scripts that works on [this](http://www.pa.msu.edu/services/computing/faq/auto-redirect.html) site.

But I don't know how to stop the script when its function is done. Any suggestion? I'm totally a noob with this language.

This is the script what I have choose:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 window.setTimeout('window.location="example.blogspot.com"; ',2000);
 // -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the script"? When that script runs, the page will reload and everything on the original page (including the script) will be unloaded. Nothing left to run, nothing left to stop.

Comment: You could set a return; when the function is completed.

Comment: when a script has nothing to do, it wont do anything more ... this script simply redirects to a different site after 2 seconds ... script wont run after the new page  loads

Comment: @Paul: I mean to let them run only one time, not continuosly like a loop.

Comment: @Dillinger: I'm not able with this language. I don't know where to start to modify that script.. :/

Comment: @Jaromanda X: I don't find a scripts like run like I want..

Comment: @Warmuser There's no loop, nothing running continuously. Do you mean that if they hit the same landing page again, you *don't* want to run the script? So once, per-user, ever? One of your other comments implies that you want to redirect through an adfly link if someone visits you from elsewhere. That sounds vaguely click-fraud-ish, and would probably be detected (and punished) by the ad network.

Comment: @Paul I know some sites what use this method, also from different years. And never happens to them. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.AddEventListener("DOMContentLoaded","CallThis");

function CallThis(){
    window.location="www.blah.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate,
Do you want to redirect the user to a different page or do you want to redirect him to the same page and that puts you in a loop ?

If you want to redirect a user to a different page the second the page loads use the following command :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() { 
        window.location.replace("http://someplaceamazing.com");
    }
</script>
```

if you want to redirect a user to the same page (reload the page) but not reload it everytime, just a single time use this :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        if(!window.location.hash) {
            window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to redirect the user from my blog to an adfly link that open the same page. It's a smart method to get a view. :)

Comment: Will be better If the waiting time remain.